# Python- Reading From Text File to Graph

Tags: python

I am trying to read from the file and then create a graph. So far all sources I found show how to read from file that already has numbers separated. The one I am trying to read has string and numbers together but I only wish to read the numbers and store them in a list and then graph it.
Here is what I got so far:

The File: myfile.txt

```
idn: 5005.4138976165706, KIA: 4599.75260966792395, 0:13:14:777
idn: 5056.2037879590774, KIA: 4699.82706117492083, 0:43:15:740
idn: 5350.4060664372547, KIA: 5060.1269162033709, 0:36:16:193
idn: 5856.9900832066719, KIA: 5750.5454873574647, 0:73:16:596
idn: 6750.5454969281304, KIA: 5924.8231401979547, 0:34:16:983
idn: 7857.6999942485903, KIA: 6658.2213250407524, 0:37:17:367
idn: 9353.9256513794773, KIA: 7874.88099297899654, 0:32:17:741
```

First one is the ID number of the person, second one is the amount of the car they sold and third one is when, timestamp. I wanted to graph the first two and possibly the third one or store the third one in different list for future uses.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for graph
idn = [] # create list
kia = [] # # create list
time = []
for line in open('myfile.txt', 'r'): #read only loop every line
    lines = [i for i in line.split()]
    idn.append(float(lines[0]))
    kia.append(float(lines[1]))
    time.append(float(lines[2]))


plt.title("Sales Numbers")
plt.xlabel('Salesman ID')
plt.ylabel('Kia sold')
plt.yticks(kia)
plt.plot(idn, kia, marker = 'o', c = 'g')
  
plt.show()
```

When I use append(float(lines[x])) I get
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'id: 5005.4138976165706'`
which makes sense.

In short, I wanted to read the first line and get the ID number as a list written into idn, and same thing for `kia` and `timestamp`. And then use `kia` and `idn` for graph.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv(sep=':\s|,\s', names=['idn', 'Salesman ID', 'brand', 'Kia sold', 'timestamp'])

fig = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='Salesman ID', y='Kia sold', marker='o', color='g')
fig.set_title('Sales Numbers')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Seaborn Plot]